# How to remove quotations ( Name "of" the excel.xlsx) within the name of excel file

Tags: vba, excel

My macro runs and pick the name of of the report from a list of access table. But Sometimes I get error anytime a name has " " around it. For example report "WIP" (S8789080)_07_20_15.xlsx

I would get the error because of "WIP". How do I add another code to remove " " from the word WIP?   Attached is my full code.

```
Option Compare Database
Public Function CreatePMReports()

    'Turn Warnings Off
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Create List of Master Project ID's - all of them
        DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qmaktbltMasterProjectID")

        'This is for only creating certain PM reports
        'DoCmd.OpenQuery ("qmaktbltMasterProjectID_oneoff")

    'Create Reports
        PMReports

    MsgBox ("Weekly PM Reports Complete")

    'Turn Warnings On
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Function

Public Sub PMReports()

' Set Variables

    'Turn Warnings Off
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False

    'Access
    Dim db As Database
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim ssql As String
    Dim ssql2 As String
    Dim sVariable1 As String
    Dim rptpath As String
    Dim rptName As String
    Dim tmpRptData As String

    'Excel
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkbk As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWkbk2 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlwkbk3 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSht As Excel.Worksheet

    'Get List of Master Prject ID's
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim DataDate As Date
    ssq1 = "SELECT * FROM Calendar"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT *FROM calendar")
    DataDate = rst.Fields("reporting date")

    ssql = "SELECT * FROM tbltMasterProjectID"
    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbltMasterProjectID")
    rst.MoveFirst

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Loop through whatever records are actually in the master project table, could be one - all per qmaktblMasterProjectID or it's oneoff equivalent

    Do While rst.EOF <> True
        sVariable2 = rst.Fields("Key")
        sVariable1 = rst.Fields("Master Project ID")

        'Set Report Path/Name
        rptpath = ("G:\TRANS\PPM\9. Enterprise Portfolio & Queue\Clarity Extract\DB and Dashboards\Combined Database\RM DBs\PM\" & sVariable2 & "_" & Format(DataDate, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsm")
        rptName = ("" & sVariable1 & "_" & Format(DataDate, "mm-dd-yy") & ".xlsm")

        'Set Temp Rpt Data Path
        tmpRptData = ("C:\DATA\BRM\_Templates\Tmp_PMReportData.xlsx")

        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'Create Workbook for Master Project

        'Set the application
        Set xlApp = New Excel.Application

        'Make the Application Visible
        xlApp.Visible = False

        'Set the workbook and the filepath 'Change "C:\Book1.xls " to your own filepath and Workbook name
        Set xlWkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\DATA\BRM\_Templates\Template - PM.xlsm ")

        'Set the worksheet that you want the workbook to open on
        xlApp.Sheets("Data").Select

        'Create Workbook Name for PM report
        xlWkbk.SaveAs (rptpath)

        'Create Workbook Name for PM report
        xlWkbk.Close (rptpath)

        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        'Export Project Data

        ' Update Current Master Project ID
        db.Execute ("UPDATE tbltCurrentMasterProjectID SET CurrentMasterProjectID = '" & sVariable1 & "'")

        ' Export Current Master Project PM View
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "A-Weekly - PMView", tmpRptData

        'Export PM View All Resource Data
        DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "A-Weekly - PMView-rsc", tmpRptData

        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        ' Copy Data to Correct Tabs

        'Open Workbook
        xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
        Set xlWkbk2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(rptpath)
        Set xlwkbk3 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(tmpRptData)

        'Copy PMView
        xlwkbk3.Sheets("A_Weekly___PMView").Select
        xlwkbk3.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        xlwkbk3.ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy

        xlWkbk2.Activate
        xlWkbk2.Sheets("Data").Select
        xlWkbk2.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        xlWkbk2.ActiveSheet.Paste
        xlWkbk2.ActiveSheet.Visible = False

        ' Copy PM View All Resource Data
        xlwkbk3.Activate
        xlwkbk3.Sheets("A_Weekly___PMView_rsc").Select
        xlwkbk3.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        xlwkbk3.ActiveSheet.Cells.Copy

        xlWkbk2.Activate
        xlWkbk2.Sheets("ProjData").Select
        xlWkbk2.ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
        xlWkbk2.ActiveSheet.Paste
        xlWkbk2.RefreshAll
        xlWkbk2.RefreshAll
        xlWkbk2.RefreshAll
        xlWkbk2.ActiveSheet.Visible = False

        'Delete TmpPMView Data
        xlwkbk3.Activate
        xlwkbk3.Sheets("A_Weekly___PMView_rsc").Select
        xlwkbk3.Sheets("A_Weekly___PMView").Select
        xlwkbk3.ActiveSheet.Delete
        xlwkbk3.Sheets("A_Weekly___PMView_rsc").Select
        xlwkbk3.ActiveSheet.Delete

        'Close Workbooks
        xlWkbk2.Save
        xlWkbk2.Close (rptpath)
        xlwkbk3.Save
        xlwkbk3.Close (tmpRptData)

        xlApp.Quit

        'Turn everything off otherwise yo will have problems with your spreadsheet
        Set xlApp = Nothing
        Set xlWkbk = Nothing
        Set xlSht = Nothing

        '----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        rst.MoveNext

    Loop

    rst.Close
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub

Private Sub test()

DoCmd.SetWarnings True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the replace function.

```
Dim str as string
str = Replace(str, """", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rptName = Replace(rptName, Chr(34), "")
```

Comment: Thanks! but every report name could have more or less than 34 characters?